# is it possible to emultate oracle partitioning with SQLAlchemy or any ORM tools?

Tags: oracle, orm, oracle10g, sqlalchemy, partitioning

- i'm almost a newbie to database stuffs.
- we are using oracle 10g standard edition as our datastore.
- +30m new rows are being inserted to a single table daily.(it's the hugest amount among what we've been managing so far)
- the rows will be displayed in a web page as a grid which supports ordering and paging.
- we were going to partition table by it's date range but found out partitioning feature wasn't on 10 SE, so we have to upgrade it to EE and need to get support by Oracle engineer.
- as an alternative for EE I'm going to stick with SE and will make new table every hour(or every day) and use sharding or vertical partitioning features on SQLAlchemy.

  1. can I join the sharded table with others?
  2. can I sort sharded rows and gather them as if they were same table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're going to spend a pound to save a penny. Are you sure the cost of EE is greater than the development/maintenance cost of doing it yourself? Just saying :)

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy has some sharding options build-in, although will never be as convenient as Oracle EE ofcourse ;)

You can view an example here: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/browser/examples/sharding/attribute_shard.py